# RStudio not working after upgrading R 4.0.1 to R 4.1.2 using HomeBrew?

Tags: r, homebrew

I had a perfectly fine working R version of 4.0.1. However, after I upgrade it via brew update, then it does not work. I have the following screenshots.
Anyone can help?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The following is the output of terminal: (base) yasins-MacBook-Pro:~ yasinasar$ r
dyld[6569]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/11/libgcc_s.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.18/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.18.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/gcc/11/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.2/lib/R/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file)Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/11/libgcc_s.1.dylib

Comment: Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/gcc/11/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.2/lib/R/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file)Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/11/libgcc_s.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/gcc/11/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.2/lib/R/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6

Comment: Try installing R from CRAN instead of using Homebrew.

Comment: Thanks, I was using CRAN version but I had problems using RCPP package due to gcc fortran. So I had to switch to the brew.

Comment: Yes, you generally need to use the same compiler as was used to build R, especially with C++.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have CRAN version of R 4.1.2 and I am getting some warnings after I compile Rcpp.Armadillo codes such as

```
sourceCpp(code = '
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export(name = "MMv_arma_slow")]]
arma::vec MMv_arma_I(arma::mat& A, arma::mat& B, arma::vec& y) {
   arma::mat C = A * B;
   return C * y;
}') 

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
```

Actually, I checked this directory and see that I have "x86_64-apple-darwin21" instead of "x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0".
The function works fine but why do I get this warning? Any comments?